# Monkey and banana solution doesn't stop after grabbing the banana (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have this code to represent the famous monkey and banana problem in Prolog detailed [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_monkey_and_banana_problem.htm) :

```
init(state(atdoor,onfloor,atwindow,hasnot)).
goal(state(_,_,_,has)).

move(state(middle,onbox,middle,hasnot),grab,state(middle,onbox,middle,has)).
move(state(Pos,onfloor,Pos,Has),climb,state(Pos,onbox,Pos,Has)).
move(state(L1,onfloor,L1,Has),push(L1,L2),state(L2,onfloor,L2,Has)).
move(state(L1,onfloor,Pos,Has),walk(L1,L2),state(L2,onfloor,Pos,Has)).

solve(State) :- goal(State).
solve(State1) :-move(State1,Move,State2),solve(State2).
solve(State1) :- init(State1),solve(State1).
```

For some reason, calling solve with the initial state returns true, but it returns true infinitely. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What is the "famous monkey and banana problem"?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_monkey_and_banana_problem.htm @Enigmativity

Comment: @Enigmativity It is a graph search problem where some labels have the name "monkey" and others "banana" and which in the early days of AI was sold as having something to do with planning and monkeys grabbing bananas  [but you knew that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_and_banana_problem). (Of course, the real difficulty is not that search problem, it is in reducing the real world to that search problem.)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution to your problem starting with the initial state (the one from `init/1`) using just the first and second clause of `solve/1` then you would have infinitely solutions when the third clause is tested with backtracking.

Note that the third clause unifies parameter `State1` with the initial state and then calls recursively. Therefore if the call to `init(State1)` succeeds it will either provide infinitely the same solution or enter in an infinite loop.

I believe you should move the third clause to another procedure:

```
solve_problem(State):- 
  init(State),
  solve(State).
```

You would probably also want to keep the moves that solve the problem, for example changing `solve/1` to `solve/2` to keep track of every step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the change to the third clause, would this just change how I query the solution? Or would I also change other calls of `solve` to `solve_problem`?

Comment: @decheftw you would change the initial call from solve to solve_problem